# Eclipse shows Debug Window over the code

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-kepler

I started to use the Eclipse Kepler this week and there is a new feature which is annoying me a lot.

When I'm in a Debug Perspective with the source screen maximized, some times, the Debug Screen opens over the source code. This behaviour bother me because the Debug Screen covers the code making it impossible to see.

Anybody knows what do I need to do to disable this feature?

Answer (score 0):

I agree that it's annoying but the behavior as been in eclipse for many years...

You have two options; restore the Debug stack  (just hit the restore button on the element in the Trim) or drag the trim element to the right side trim. If you do the latter then even though the Debug view will still open it's less likely to obscure the code.